# React Native buttons multi touch

Tags: android, react-native

I'm making a "joystick" app on android for my RC-car and I want be able to press two or more buttons at the same time to allow more precise control.

But, right now I can only press one button and the others do not respond until I release pressed button. They are even do not change their opacity, so it's not a problem in the app's logic. And click handlers also do not perform time critical operations, so I don't think that UI is just stuck.

Here's the code for my buttons:

```
<R.View>  
  {this.btn(Car.Transmission.Forward, 'Forward')}
</R.View>
<R.View flexDirection="row">
  {this.btn(Car.Transmission.Left, 'Left')}
  {this.btn(Car.Transmission.Stop, 'Stop')}
  {this.btn(Car.Transmission.Right, 'Right')}
</R.View>
<R.View>
  {this.btn(Car.Transmission.Backward, 'Backward')}
</R.View>

btn(transmission, text) {
  return <MyButton 
    onPressIn={() => {
      this.drive(transmission)
    }} 
    onPressOut={() => {
      this.drive(Car.Transmission.Neutral)
    }}
    text={text} />
}

export class MyButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var {onPressIn, onPressOut, text, disabled} = this.props
    let textStyle = disabled ? [style.button, style.disabled] : [style.button]

    return (
      <R.TouchableOpacity onPressIn={onPressIn} onPressOut={onPressOut} disabled={disabled}>
        <R.Text style={textStyle} >{text}</R.Text>
      </R.TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

Maybe I should not be using `TouchableOpacity`?

**EDIT:** I've almost done it, but... when I receive touch location in `onPanResponderMove` callback my `nativeEvent.locationY` value jumps like a crazy (161, 0, 163, 11, 29, ...) when I click at the same point on the screen... First, I thought this is because of USB-cable and charging, but over Wi-Fi I get the same results. That's strange. Any ideas?

Comment: PanResponder is probably your friend here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html

Comment: Indeed. Playing with their example right now, thanks!

Comment: I know this is awhile later, did you end up being able to receive two buttons at once? @saintcrawler